# Nginx Proxy Pass mydomain.com/12345/ to 12345.serverdomain.com with regex

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to be able to proxy_pass mydomain.com/12345/ where 12345 is an id to 12345.serverdomain.com.

I can do this with the following.

```
location /12345/ {
   proxy_pass https://12345.serverdomain.com;
}
```

But I want the id (12345) to be dynamic. Something similar to.

```
location /([0-9]+)/ {
    proxy_pass https://$1.serverdomain.com;
}
```

I have not had any luck using regex to solve this problem.

Any suggestions. I am new to nginx.

**Update**

It looks like the followign works

```
location ~*/([0-9]+)/? {
    proxy_pass https://$1.serverdomain.com;
}
```

But now I am getting the following error:

```
*7 no resolver defined to resolve 12345.serverdomain.com
```

Comment: Have you defined a `resolver` statement? See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver).